# How to unnest an array of varchar in presto sql

Tags: presto

I have a column `description` with varchar values that I want to unnest to retrieve the stallid and itemid as separate columns.

```
[{"stallid":6771032,"itemid":12232},{"stallid":6771033,"itemid":12233}]
```

[image]

I tried the following syntax but it doesn't work.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(description) from tableA
```

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select item['stallid'] as stallid, item['itemid'] as itemid
from 
(select cast(json_parse('[{"stallid":6771032,"itemid":12232},{"stallid":6771033,"itemid":12233}]') as array<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>) as items) CROSS JOIN UNNEST(items) AS items(item);

 stallid | itemid 
---------+--------
 6771032 | 12232  
 6771033 | 12233
```

https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse